# Does the download of Scala IDE 4.0.0 for Eclipse include SBT?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, scala-ide

The download page at [scala-ide.org](http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html) for the pre-configured Scala IDE for Eclipse (4.0.0 Release) states that its *content* includes SBT 0.13.6. I downloaded the Mac OS X 64-bit version, and found that the `/plugins` directory indeed contains a jar file called `org.scala-ide.sbt.full.library_0.13.6.v-2...`  Is this a replacement for having a separate installation of SBT on one's development machine, perhaps facilitating some tighter integration between the Scala Eclipse plugin and SBT?  If so, how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does indeed include sbt. It is used internally to control the build, notably the incremental compiler.

It isn't a replacement for having sbt installed on your machine, it isn't really accessible from outside scala-ide.

As for tighter integration, not at the minute.

Comment: This response is from a co-author of [SBT in Action](http://www.manning.com/suereth2/).  Thanks!